# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:1054 Unknown column 'ine_puebla.'in'where clause'

Tags: laravel, json, laravel-5, datatables

Tengo el siguiente archivo JSON que se genera por medio de una consulta a la base de datos en laravel y necesito eliminar una parte que me genera un error a la hora de realizar la búsqueda.

**Esta es el error generado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La solución esta en eliminar una parte del archivo JSON de la
>   consulta.

El archivo generado es el siguiente:

```
{
  "draw": 0,
  "recordsTotal": 5,
  "recordsFiltered": 5,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "apellidopaterno": "MORALES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ACEVEDO",
      "nombre": "JOSE ANTONIO",
      "fechanacimiento": "19880201",
      "actividad": "EMPLEADO",
      "calle": "C 3 NORTE",
      "numero": "5",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "COL CENTRO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "apellidopaterno": "MORALES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ACEVEDO",
      "nombre": "JOSE DAVID",
      "fechanacimiento": "19911213",
      "actividad": "EMPLEADO",
      "calle": "C 5 NORTE",
      "numero": "10",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "BARR DE SAN ANTONIO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "apellidopaterno": "MORALES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ACEVEDO",
      "nombre": "MAGDALENA",
      "fechanacimiento": "19820209",
      "actividad": "EMPLEADO",
      "calle": "C 5 NORTE",
      "numero": "10",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "BARR SAN ANTONIO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "apellidopaterno": "MORALES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ACEVEDO",
      "nombre": "MARGARITA",
      "fechanacimiento": "19770101",
      "actividad": "AMA DE CASA",
      "calle": "C 4 PONIENTE",
      "numero": "503",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "BARR SAN ANTONIO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "apellidopaterno": "MORALES",
      "apellidomaterno": "ACEVEDO",
      "nombre": "MICHAEL",
      "fechanacimiento": "19950303",
      "actividad": "TRABAJADOR POR SU CUENTA",
      "calle": "C 5 NORTE",
      "numero": "10",
      "interior": null,
      "colonia": "BARR SAN ANTONIO",
      "codigopostal": "75120"
    }
  ],
  "queries": [
    {
      "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `ine_puebla`) count_row_table",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": "0.66"
    },
    {
      "query": "select * from `ine_puebla`",
      "bindings": [

      ],
      "time": "0.52"
    }
  ],
  "input": [

  ]
}
```

La parte que necesito eliminar es la siguiente:

```
"queries": [
        {
          "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `ine_puebla`) count_row_table",
          "bindings": [

          ],
          "time": "0.66"
        },
        {
          "query": "select * from `ine_puebla`",
          "bindings": [

          ],
          "time": "0.52"
        }
      ],
```

Resulta que estoy trabajando con datatable laravel y cuando hago la consulta me agrega en el archivo JSON este codigo y me genera un error cuando hago la busqueda en el datatable.
Eliminando esta parte no tendría ese problema pero no se como hacerlo.
Pues le envio el archivo JSON al datatable por Ajax.

Al parecer es un error con el paquete

> yajra/laravel-datatables

Pero nadie me da una solución.

**MENSAJE ERROR**

> DataTables warning: table id=laravel_datatable-Exception Message:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:1054 Unknown column
>   'ine_puebla.'in'where clause'(SQL:select count(*) as aggregate
>   from(select'1'as 'row_count' from 'ine_puebla' where
>   (LOWER('ine_puebla'.'')LIKE%2% or LOWER('ine_puebla'.'nombre')LIKE%2%
>   or LOWER('ine_puebla'.'apellidopaterno')LIKE%2% or
>   LOWER('ine_puebla'.'apellidomaterno')LIKE%2% or
>   LOWER('ine_puebla'.'fechanacimiento')LIKE%2% or
>   LOWER('ine_puebla'.'actividad')LIKE%2%)) count_row_table)

Comment: Por favor añade el mensaje de error como texto

Comment: Pues yo veo un error a nivel de la consulta, dice ahí que una columna no fue encontrada, lo cual es indicio de que no esta escrita correctamente o no existe, entonces ayudaría ver dicha consulta

Comment: Agregue el error que genera. Ya consulte en el foro de Datatable.net y me dicen que el problema lo genera el paquete yajra/laravel-datatables y la verdad sigo buscando en sus foros y no veo solución por eso encontré que si no tiene ese código ya si funciona bien el datatable

Comment: Si es lo que normalmente uno puede pensar porque realmente esa no es una columna es el nombre de la tabla. Pero la tabla no tiene error.

Answer (score 0):

Estas queriendo eliminar la propiedad `queries`.

Segun la documentacion, es posible eliminar completamente una propiedad de un archivo **JSON** con el operador `delete`.

> > Tendrías que hacer `delete.miArchivoJson.queries` y trabajar con el nuevo resultado.

Comment: Así seria en el controlador en Laravel?

Comment: Desconozco. pero vos decis que en alguna parte de tu codigo, se realiza una consulta a la base de datos, y la misma retorna un archivo JSON. Luego, a este mismo JSON lo utilizas para imprimir datos en pantalla. Cierto? Bueno, en el medio de esas dos acciones, proba agregar una linea de codigo que solo sea ``delete.miArchivoJson.queries;`` en el archivo .js que corresponda.

Comment: Mi solución se limita a eliminar la propiedad  ``queries`` del archivo JSON, que según lo que expusiste, es lo que necesitas hacer. Si no nos entendemos, por ahi deberías mostrarme un poco como esta el código a ver si te puedo ayudar un poco mas.

Comment: Esta es la consulta que genera el archivo JSON. Lo que hago es por medio de Eloquent el ORM de Laravel hacer un SELECT * FROM.  `return datatables()->of(DB::table('ine_puebla'))->toJson();` Pero al hacer ese select me agrega esos codigos al final. Que sucede si en lugar de hacer eso se genera el siguiente codigo:   `return datatables()->of(DB::table('ine_puebla')->OrderBy('id')->get())->make(true);` No me lanza ningun error pero sucede que la consulta genera casi 5 millones de registros y con esa ultima linea demora demasiado. Estoy trabajando con la función server-side

Comment: Bien, probemos esto. Guardar en una variable la consulta, algo como ``$miArchivoJson = SELECT * FROM. return datatables()->of(DB::table('ine_puebla'))->toJson();`` Ahora el JSON se encuentra en la variable ``$miArchivoJson``. Tenemos que eliminarle ahora la propiedad ``queries`` agregando la linea que puse en el primer comentario, y seguir el normal flujo del sistema.

Comment: Ya probe y no me funciona

Comment: Entonces no creo que el problema sea el que indicas, ya que copie tu json, le aplique la funcion indicada, y quedo limpio de la propiedad queries.

Comment: El problema es que lo trabajo en laravel y cuando lo hago asi no me funciona con laravel